# State machines testing automatization

Tags: c, algorithm, state-machine

I am wondering if there is any test procedure to check if a state machine state cannot stay forever in one of it's states, it will run in an infinite loop through different states if they are available.

So i am thinking about a kind of a brute force that will check all the possible transitions.

As an example I give a very simple state machine. It can be seen from the pic, that State 1 can switch to State 1 itself, or to State 2; State 2 goes to State 3 or State 6 and so on.

[image: Exaple of the state machine]

In my case there is the one that has enclosed state machines (the case when one of the states has it's own state machine)
My code is written in C.

Thanks for any hints

Comment: A state machine can be modelled as a graph, with the edges the transitions. Then you can check if there is a cycle in the graph.

Comment: Are you asking for a (static?) analyzer tool? This would be off-topic as it's a request for an off-site resource. Or are you interested in writing such a tool yourself? That's clearly too broad, therefore off-topic as well...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie that's a good advice to consider it as a graph, thanks

Comment: In a state machine, state 1 cannot "go" to state 1. It stays in state 1. You must determine whether there are conditions for it to leave the state. in general, that will happen when a variable changes value. You can decompose a state into an own state machine that you can analyze the same way.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I am interested in any help how to solve such problems, in my case there is a source code for a device, and I have to check if it can stay in any of the states forever

Comment: If you are testing your state machine which is a software, unit testing may help to evaluate each transition. one test for one transition. Depends how much coverage you want.

Comment: https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1548